# What's the collective term for the concepts of truncation, gyroelongation, snubification, etc., for polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra, polytopes

I recently watched a video on a youtube channel "DONG" led by Michael from Vsauce titled "Making every strictly convex deltahedron"

Some concepts like *elongation*, *gyroelongation*, *expansion*, *snubification* were introduced. I also found concepts like *truncation*, *rectification*, and others, on Wolfram MathWorld.

I'm just interested, what do these concepts are called collectively. I'm looking for something like "polyhedra transformations (?)"

And also, as a secondary question, where can I find well-formed source explaining much of those concepts in orderly manner? MathWorld doesn't provide all the details and doesn't have a page listing those "transformations" one by one. Wikipedia lacks details too.

Comment: There is no exhaustive list of transformation names. There is only the list of ones you are interested in.

Comment: There's a big list at the Wikipedia page on [Conway polyhedron notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation), although "Note that many more operations exist than have been named". Maybe the term *local (orientation-preserving) symmetry-preserving operations* is relevant.

Comment: @Rahul thank you!

Comment: The process usually appears the other way round. One defines a set of polyhedra (e.g. the uniform ones, the Johnson solids, etc.) enumerates those, and then tries to provide some names to the contained members. I.e. those names usually are given from scratch, are meant to be descriptive.